# Spring Boot migration from 2.3.6.RELEASE to 2.4.0 and json ClassCastException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nimbus-jose-jwt

I have a Java project which has a dependency of SpringBoot version 2.3.6.RELEASE. However, I'm in trouble trying to upgrade to 2.4.0 version. In the project nothing else was changed, only version of SpringBoot. Since then the application throws the following error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to net.minidev.json.JSONObject
```

I did some comparison of maven dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree`) and found out that probably some significant changes have been done for **nimbus-jose-jwt** and **json-smart** libs.

2.3.6.RELEASE

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:8.19:compile (version managed from 8.20.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.3.1:provided (scope managed from compile)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.3.5.RELEASE:compile
```

2.4.0

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.1.2:compile (version managed from 9.0.1)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.4.1:compile
```

As can be seen above **nimbus-jose-jwt** has been updated from 8.19 to 9.1.2. Moreover, **json-smart** is not anymore part of **nimbus-jose-jwt** in 2.4.0.

The root cause is probably this change https://connect2id.com/blog/nimbus-jose-jwt-9
However, what should be done in order to prevent this exception?

Comment: Hello, can you show some of your code? Especially if the line throwing exception is under your own codebase.

Comment: Figure out what is using the old dependency and upgrade that as well. You cannot "just" upgrade 1 version, you have to take into account these things. It is probably some of your code (or another library) that you are using that uses the old one. Either upgrade that as well or modify the code. If not you cannot use Spring Boot 2.4 (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You could override the default versions of jars nimbus-jose-jwt and json-smart, by adding the older version explicitly in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/14898

In my case - I had to upgrade to 2.5.7 Springboot version and the nimbus-jose-jwt:jar version came with SB-2.5.7 is 9.10.1.

```
    org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.5.3:compile - version managed from 4.2.15.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:5.5.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.13:compile - version managed from 5.3.11; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.10.1:compile
```

After downgrading the nimbus-jose-jwt to 8.20 the app started working.